# Returning ID from database / validation

Tags: php, database, validation, laravel

Im trying do return a ID after a registration to echo it in a massage . I try but it doesnt work.

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $rules = [
    'name' => ['required'],
    'surname' => ['required'],
    'mac_address' => ['required','min:17','max:17','unique:registrations'],
    'phone' => ['between:9,11'],
  ];

  $this->validate($request,$rules);

  $mac_address = $request->input('mac_address');

  $registration = Registration::create($request->all());

$id = Registration::select('id')
              ->where('mac_address',$mac_address)
              ->get();

    return redirect('registration') -> with("message","Your ID :",$id);
}
```

And Second question . Is there and validation option to request first Big letter in Name ?

Thx for all help

Comment: As a note, $registration may have an ID associated with it

Comment: For your second question, you'd want to use the regular expression validation rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will be:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $rules = [
    'name' => ['required'],
    'surname' => ['required'],
    'mac_address' => ['required','min:17','max:17','unique:registrations'],
    'phone' => ['between:9,11'],
  ];

  $this->validate($request, $rules);

  $mac_address = $request->input('mac_address');

  $registration = Registration::create($request->all());

  $id = $registration->id;

  return redirect('registration')->with("message","Your ID : ".$id);
}
```

The Laravel model (Registration extends Model) returns the last inserted details, so you can get all of the data by using the `$registration`.

Hope this works!

PS, I don't know if there is a validation option to request first Big letter in Name.

Comment: No it dont work becouse i dont insert it , ID is auto-incremented be database

Comment: So you want to get the mac_address from the user?

Comment: i try get id from registered user by mac_address becouse it is unique

Comment: Yes, with the code above you get the latest user id.

Comment: What's the error? Is the user added? Can you dump $registration?

Comment: User is added to database and I get only message Your ID :

Comment: Can you dump($registration); in your controller?

Comment: i put it in controller and something like this shown : http://files.tinypic.pl/i/00787/q5qdsumz9a1b.jpg

Comment: Can you expend "original"

Comment: There you have the id, I see al little error in the code, hope it works now!

Comment: No it dont work like i want . http://files.tinypic.pl/i/00787/h4htwsnkfetp.jpg in green message arena I want "Your ID : " and id gained after registration

Comment: Did you change with("message","Your ID : ",$id); to with("message","Your ID : ".$id);

I replaced the , with a .

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the id of the user through the $registration variable,
try this :

```
 return redirect('registration')->with("message","Your ID :", $registration->id);
```